# What is wrong with the definition in this typescript file

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects which I want to use when evaluating some input from a form. However I keep on getting a type error  when evaluating the variable this.ptp. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

```
export class AppCadComponent implements OnInit {
  ptpForm: FormGroup;
  ptp: number = 0;
  ptp_list = [
    {"leeftijd":"30-39", ptp:0, "geslacht":"man", "score":1},
    {"leeftijd":"30-39", ptp:1, "geslacht":"vrouw", "score":2},
    {"leeftijd":"40-49", ptp:2, "geslacht":"man", "score":3},
    {"leeftijd":"40-49", ptp:3, "geslacht":"vrouw", "score":4},]

  answer: {};

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ptpForm = this.fb.group ({
      ptp_age: [''],
      ptp_geslacht: [''],
    });
  }

  this.ptp = 1

  var antwoord = this.ptp_list.filter(function (item) {
    return item.leeftijd == formValue.ptp_age && item.geslacht ==formValue.ptp_geslacht && item.ptp == this.ptp
  });
  alert (answer.score);
}
```

Comment: please add the error message as well

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (when evaluating this.ptp)

Comment: Why this.ptp and the var antwoord is outside the component and not in an function inside ?

Comment: when attaching a code, format it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the code to get the "answoord" variable is outside your component but anyway let's do some quick clean up in your code :

```js
export interface PtpItem {
   leeftijd: string;
   ptp: number;
   geslacht: string;
   score: number;
}

export type PtpList = PtpItem[];

export class AppCadComponent implements OnInit {
  ptpForm: FormGroup;
  ptp: number = 0;
  ptp_list: PtpList  = [
    {"leeftijd":"30-39", ptp:0, "geslacht":"man", "score":1},
    {"leeftijd":"30-39", ptp:1, "geslacht":"vrouw", "score":2},
    {"leeftijd":"40-49", ptp:2, "geslacht":"man", "score":3},
    {"leeftijd":"40-49", ptp:3, "geslacht":"vrouw", "score":4}
  ]
  answer: {};

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ptpForm = this.fb.group ({
      ptp_age: new FormControl(''),
      ptp_geslacht: new FormControl('')
    });

    // maybe this.ptp should be there ? To be confirmed
    this.ptp = 1;
  }

   getAntWoord(formValue: any): PtpList {
     if (!this.ptp || !formValue) {
       return []; // We don't want to filter if this.ptp is not initialized or formGroup is null
     }

     return this.ptp_list.filter((item: PtpItem) => item.leeftijd === formValue.ptp_age && item.geslacht === formValue.ptp_geslacht && item.ptp === this.ptp);
   }
}
```

I don't know how you define your answer member variable actually, but you can use the getAntWoord function by passing the formValue in param.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign this.ptp only inside a class method/constructor or during definition in general.

You can do this in constructor or ngOnInit

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
     this.ptp = 1;
  }
```

or

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.ptp = 1;
}
```